# Plotly two subplots controlled by one slider

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Having a issue here with plotly trying to plot two subplots all controlled by one slider.
This should be pretty simple but I cant see to get it to work.
I have been following: https://plot.ly/python/sliders/
and a lot of other posts but still seem to be having issues.

I am using two dfs for each of the two subplots plots and trying to get it to change which row will be visible with the step change in the slider.

Here is where I am up to. First time using plotly so any help and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import chart_studio.plotly as py


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100, 120, 100, 105, 110], 
                'B':[130, 120, 100, 105, 110],
                'C':[110, 110, 140, 115, 120],
                'D':[140, 120, 160, 120, 130],                   
                'E':[150, 130, 100, 105, 150]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[140, 150, 110, 115, 120], 
                'B':[150, 120, 100, 105, 110],
                'C':[120, 120, 110, 115, 120],
                'D':[170, 140, 120, 125, 150],                   
                'E':[140, 180, 115, 115, 140]})


fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,shared_xaxes=True)

# Add traces, one for each slider step
for step in range(len(df.index)):
    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="#00CED1", width=2),
            name="Time = " + str(step),
            x=df.columns[0:],
            y=df.loc[step]),row=1, col=1)

#for step in range(len(df2.index)): Tried this does not work

    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="red", width=2),
            name="Time = " + str(step),
            x=df2.columns[0:],
            y=df2.loc[step]),row=2, col=1)


fig.data[1].visible = True


# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    step = dict(method="restyle",
        args=["visible", [False] * len(fig.data)],
    )
    step["args"][1][i] = True
    #step["args"][1][i+1] = True # This shows them both but still not correct (different row numbers)

    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Time:  "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Temperature", range=[-160, 260],nticks=30, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Pressure", range=[-169, 260],nticks=30, row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders, title="Time Series - Interactive", template ="plotly_white")

fig.update_layout(width=800,height=600,)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some one from the Plotly Forums answered my Question.
Here is what I did.

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import random


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)], 
                'B':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'C':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'D':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],                  
                'E':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'F':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'G':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'H':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'I':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'J':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'K':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'L':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'M':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'N':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'O':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'P':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)]       
                })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)], 
                'B':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'C':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'D':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],                  
                'E':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'F':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'G':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'H':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'I':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'J':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'K':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'L':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'M':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'N':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'O':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)],
                'P':[random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200),random.randint(1,200)]       
                })


fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,shared_xaxes=True,vertical_spacing  = 0.25)

# Add traces, one for each slider step
for step in range(len(df.index)):
    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="#00CED1", width=2),
            name="Time = " + str(step),
            x=df.columns[0:],
            y=df.loc[step]),row=1, col=1)

#for step in range(len(df2.index)):# Tried this does not work
    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="red", width=2),
            name="Time = " + str(step),
            x=df2.columns[0:],
            y=df2.loc[step]),row=2, col=1)


# Create and add slider
steps = []

for i in range(0, len(fig.data), 2):
    step = dict(
        method="restyle",
        args=["visible", [False] * len(fig.data)],
    )
    step["args"][1][i:i+2] = [True, True]
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Time:  "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Temperature", range=[-160, 260],nticks=30, row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Pressure", range=[-169, 260],nticks=30, row=2, col=1)
fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders, title="Time Series - Interactive", template ="plotly_white")




plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='name.html')
fig.show()
```